# What are the supported operators and commands in FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to compile a complete list but the sources don't agree.

Here's what I've got so far. Let me know if I'm missing anything, or if I've put anything in incorrectly.

Basic format: SELECT [fields] FROM [table] WHERE [conditions]

In the docs: now(), strlen(), substr() and strpos(), IN

Unsure:

1. AND
2. OR
3. LIMIT
4. ORDER_BY
5. OFFSET
6. Anything else?

Also: Joins are definitely out right?

Comment: Any FB employee to confirm the list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

functions supported:

```
me()
now()
rand()
strlen(...)
concat(...)
substr(...)
strpos(...)
lower(...)
upper(...)
```

operators supported:

```
AND, OR, NOT, IN, ><=, +-*/
```

OFFSET is a part of LIMIT: offset, rowcount, i.e.

```
LIMIT 5, 5
```

ORDER BY is supported, DESC, ASC is supported also, SELECT * not supported

EDIT: joins not supported but you can do subqueries

Comment: Wow! This should be in the FB documentation.